# Updated Ubuntu to 16.04 and the new Libreoffice messed up my previous version document

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I was making a document in LibreOffice from Ubuntu 14, and after updating it to 16.04, now all the words look like they are bolded, and when I use bold, it looks almost the same, just bigger. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrJau.png). The one from left was before updating and the right one is after updating.

How can I fix this? It's really awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your fonts, preferably by changing *Default* style. The old font you have used may not be supported now, either by Ubuntu or by loffice, and the replacement seems not what you wanted.